# Yii2 missing required parameter in a constructor

Tags: yii2

I've created a new `XmlResponseFormatter` and now I want to change the `rootTag`.

```
class newXmlResponseFormatter extends XmlResponseFormatter 
{  
    /**
     * @var string the name of the root element.
     *
     */
    public $rootTag;

    public function __construct($rootTag) {        
        parent::__construct();

        $this->rootTag = $rootTag;        
    }
}
```

From a controller I set that value:

```
$xmlFormater = new newXmlResponseFormatter('newRootTag');
```

In the controller that value is available, and it sets in $rootTag but it threw the following exception:

> exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Missing required parameter "rootTag" when instantiating "app\components\override\newXmlResponseFormatter".' in /var/www/html/Admin/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:451

Does anyone know what can be a problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First parameter in `XmlResponseFormatter` is `$config`, because `XmlResponseFormatter` extends `Object` class. You are [violated liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

You should rewrite your constructor like this:

```
class newXmlResponseFormatter extends XmlResponseFormatter
{
    /**
     * @var string the name of the root element.
     *
     */
    public $rootTag;

    /**
     * newXmlResponseFormatter constructor.
     *
     * @param string $rootTag
     * @param array $config
     */
    public function __construct($rootTag, $config = [])
    {
        $this->rootTag = $rootTag;

        parent::__construct($config);
    }
}
```

In yii2 you should call parent constructor **after** your code, and call parent `init` **before** your code.

`$config` need for simple configure model like this:

```
new newXmlResponseFormatter(['rootTag' => 'newRootTag']);
```

Comment: I did it as you said:
`code`
class newXmlResponseFormatter extends XmlResponseFormatter
{
    /**
     * @var string the name of the root element.
     *
     */
    public $rootTag;
    
    public function __construct($rootTag, $config = [])
    {   
        parent::init();        
        $this->rootTag = $rootTag;                
        parent::__construct($config);
    }
}`code`

Controller:
`code`$xmlFormater = new newXmlResponseFormatter('newRootTag', []);`code`

But, I still have the same error, exception...

Comment: parent `init` should be called **after** constructor in individual `init` function. Remove it from constructor and it will work :)

Comment: Still doesn't work :(
`code`
public function __construct($rootTag, $config = [])
    {        
        $this->rootTag = $rootTag;        
        
        parent::__construct($config); 
    }
public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }`code`

Comment: try remove constuctor, init, and use this: `new newXmlResponseFormatter(['rootTag' => 'newRootTag']);`

Comment: I already tried it, and it didn't work.
If I do next: "public $rootTag = 'rootTag';" in the newXmlResponseFormatter class, it works perfect, but it is not my goal to be always the same value. :(

Comment: I have resolved it, but on different way, perhaps it is weird, but it works.
In config/web.php:

'response' => [
            'formatters' => [
                'xml' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\web\XmlResponseFormatter',
                    'rootTag' => 'newRootTag'
                ]
            ],
        ]

Comment: Then, from my controller I can dynamically change that value: $response->formatters['xml']['rootTag'] = "newValue";